# C# Nested class bug?

Tags: c#, class, nested

When i make a nested class and name it B and make a variable called B, and when i try to work with it with a "this." then there stand its Ambiguous.

Shouldn't it be a bug since whenever you write "this." its obviously a variable you are trying to work with and not the class.

When i put the B class outside the A class, then it works, so i cant really see the reason why the c# creators would make it ambiguous just because its nested.

[image]

Comment: You can access any *member* that is part of the class with `this`. Members include variables but also methods, events and nested classes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot have a nested type and a member with the same name at all.
Even if you don't use `B` anywhere, your code will not compile.

Types and members within a class share the naming scope, and thus cannot share names.